# Better version of my code - bad slicing

Tags: ruby

I have passed the tests so the code works it really looks a little ugly a bit unRuby, is there a more Ruby way for this.

This is my solution

```
 def start_of_word(word, x=1)
      @word = word[0,1+(x-1)]
 end
```

These were the test to pass

```
describe "start_of_word" do
    it "returns the first letter" do
      start_of_word("hello", 1).should == "h"
    end

    it "returns the first two letters" do
      start_of_word("Bob", 2).should == "Bo"
    end

    it "returns the first several letters" do
      s = "abcdefg"
      start_of_word(s, 1).should == "a"
      start_of_word(s, 2).should == "ab"
      start_of_word(s, 3).should == "abc"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1+(x-1)` is equial to `x`.

```
def start_of_word(word, x=1)
  word[0, x]
end
```

Assigning to `@word` is not necessary to pass the tests.

Answer (score 4):

You've reimplemented `slice`. It accepts a starting index and a length:

```
def start_of_word(word, x=1)
  @word = word.slice(1, x)
end
```

Comment: For completeness - In rails you can just do `word.first(x)`

Comment: It should be `word.slice(0, x)` to pass tests.